# How do you find the php file a function is defined in in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a newbie at WordPress PHP.

I'm looking in the header.php file and it's calling:

```
<?php suffusion_before_page(); ?>
```

For this function and any other function *in WordPress*/PHP how do I find which file that function is being defined?

Comment: yeah, obviously. Is there a way to know which out of the 100s of files it is in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have SSH access to the server you can use grep to find the function definition.

```
grep -R 'function suffusion_before_page' /path/to/theme
```

If you don't you can download the theme files and search for it using a program of your choice. Notepad++ has a find in files feature.

Comment: Ok makes sense. Is there anyway within Wordpress to do that?

Comment: There is no built in feature that allows WordPress to do a search through its own source code. There might be a plugin that does it: a quick google search turned up this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/string-locator/

Comment: ok cool. I'm going to look at that plugin. Sounds like the thing I need.

Comment: Works like a champ! And it allows you to edit the file directly from the search results!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows OS, then you can use GrepWin. Check the screenshots how to use this:

**Selecting folder to search by grepwin:**
[image: Selecting folder to search by grepwin]

**Using search string in the textbox to search:**
[image: Using search string in the textbox to search]

[Grepwin Download Link](https://code.google.com/p/grepwin/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Windows you can enter something like this to command prompt:

```
find /c /i "function suffusion_before_page(" C:\path\to\wordpress\folder\*.* | find ": 0" /v
```

Change the path, of course.

Comment: Note that if that function has any defined parameters the search will fail.

Comment: "function suffusion_before_page("

Answer (score 0):

Look in your hosting cPanel site under your site directory with the rest of your files for your site. The file name is suffusion_before_page.php, which is what you should look for.

You can try and go to www.yoursite.com/wp-admin/theme-editor.php, and then control + f to bring up the search function in browser. Type in "suffusion_before_page.php", then click that file and you can see it.